# running php files in tomcat

Tags: php, tomcat

I want to run php script in tomcat
 I followed the steps as described in the link http://blog.jackneer.com/2008/10/php-5-on-tomcat-6-installation.html

But I am getting error HTTP Status 500

```
      java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: net.php.servlet.send
      net.php.servlet.send(Native Method)
      net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:190)
      net.php.servlet.service(servlet.java:214)
      javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
```

I have also copied php_java.dll,php5servlet.dll,php.ini and php5ts.dll in windows/system32 
but still no success
I am using Apache Tomcat 6.0 ,php-5.2.5 and windows 7 OS 64bit.

Comment: do you want to run php scripts or java servlets?

Comment: i want to run php scripts only

Comment: If you only need a run php scripts then why are you using tomcat? :S